# Change file type xls to xlsx REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, xlsx, xls

i'm using this lib for my ReactApp
https://github.com/zsusac/ReactHTMLTableToExcel

in this library have this function:

```
handleDownload() {
    if (!document) {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        console.error('Failed to access document object');
      }

      return null;
    }

    if (document.getElementById(this.props.table).nodeType !== 1 || document.getElementById(this.props.table).nodeName !== 'TABLE') {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        console.error('Provided table property is not html table element');
      }

      return null;
    }

    const table = document.getElementById(this.props.table).outerHTML;
    const sheet = String(this.props.sheet);
    const filename = `${String(this.props.filename)}.xls`;

    const uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
    const template =
      '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-mic' +
      'rosoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta cha' +
      'rset="UTF-8"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:Exce' +
      'lWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/>' +
      '</x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></' +
      'xml><![endif]--></head><body>{table}</body></html>';

    const context = {
      worksheet: sheet || 'Worksheet',
      table,
    };

    // If IE11
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      const fileData = [
        `${'<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-mic' + 'rosoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta cha' + 'rset="UTF-8"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:Exce' + 'lWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/>' + '</x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></' + 'xml><![endif]--></head><body>'}${table}</body></html>`,
      ];
      const blobObject = new Blob(fileData);
      document.getElementById('react-html-table-to-excel').click()(() => {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, filename);
      });

      return true;
    }

    const element = window.document.createElement('a');
    element.href =
      uri +
      ReactHTMLTableToExcel.base64(
        ReactHTMLTableToExcel.format(template, context),
      );
    element.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);

    return true;
  }
```

that one make a xls file, but i need a xlsx file, but i don't know how to change that, i tryied a lot of things, but no solution =[

theres a similar code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-custom-html-table-to-excel?file=index.js

i already used that format like that to remove one column, but i can't do the same thing for file name, anyone can help me please?

Comment: Did you try changing it to `const filename = \`${String(this.props.filename)}.xlsx;\``?

Comment: its a library, i cant change things in the library =[

Comment: It's open-source, you can fork it and add features as needed.

Comment: this function is a part of the library

Comment: but how can i do that?

Comment: o copy all the code and i create a net jsx, but something is missing, now when i download, it comes with xlsx, but with error, this is because that template?